# How can I check a JSON array using RestFixture?

Tags: rest, fixtures, fitnesse

I have a JSON array like this:

```
[
    {
        "Id": 1,
        "Host": {
            "Id": 1,
            "LoginId": "abc"
        }
    },
    {
        "Id": 2,
        "Host": {
            "Id": 3,
            "LoginId": "def"
        }
    }
]
```

I want to check the occurence of `Host.LoginId == "abc"`. If my array was in a fixed order, I could check with `jsonbody[0].Host.LoginId=="abc"`.

However, my array is not in any particular order, so I cannot check on the first element. How can I check a particular occurence anywhere in a JSON array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [GitHub](https://github.com/smartrics/RestFixture/issues/128):

RestFixture allows an expectation cell to be interpreted as JavaScript if it is preceded by `/* javascript */`. It must then return a value than can be mapped to `true` or `false`. However, the use of the `return` statement throws an error.

The following code is working as expected:

```
/* javascript */ 
var found = false; 
for(var x in jsonbody){
    if (jsonbody[x].Host.LoginId=="abc") {
        found = true;
    } 
}
found;
```

This is inserted as a whole in the fixture:

```
| GET | URL | 200 | Content-Type : application/json | /* javascript */ (etc) |
```